# How to obtain a dynamic JQuery Mobile Accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I was trying to design a basic RSS feed reader using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile. The page loads first and it takes time for the feeds to show up. I'm trying to add an accordion to each post so that the user gets to see the post title and expand the post if interested. This is the snippet i used:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
    var title = entry.title,
    link = entry.link,
    description = entry.contentSnippet,
    pubDate = entry.publishedDate;
    feedItem = feedItem + '<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a"><h3><a href="' + link + '>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '<span class="feeditemtitle">' + title + '</span>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '</a></h3>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '<h6>' + pubDate + '</h6>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '<p>' + description + '</p></div>';
}
```

I am able to get the posts on the page but there is no accordion. It renders the posts as plain HTML. I assume it is because the posts load *after* the page is loaded. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *refresh* the loaded content.

Assuming it is appended to this node `<div id="loaded-content" data-role="collapsible-set"></div>` you have to do:

```
$('.loaded-content').collapsibleset('refresh');
```

You can look at my fiddle which emulates an Ajax call and create the accordion with a delay: http://jsfiddle.net/ooflorent/FkT8H/

Comment: Wow. Works like a charm! As you said, I wrapped the whole thing in a new div and appended the content to it. And I called the refresh at the end of the loop. Thank you very much for your help! This solves my problem!

Comment: @Florent the link doesn't work can you update it? I'm looking for similar solution

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
    var title = entry.title,
    link = entry.link,
    description = entry.contentSnippet,
    pubDate = entry.publishedDate;
    feedItem = feedItem + '<div data-role="collapsible" class="accordItem" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a"><h3><a href="' + link + '>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '<span class="feeditemtitle">' + title + '</span>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '</a></h3>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '<h6>' + pubDate + '</h6>';
    feedItem = feedItem + '<p>' + description + '</p></div>';
    if(i == result.feed.entries.length-1){
        $(".accordItem").collapsible();
    }
}
```

Comment: JQuery Mobile is supposed to add an accordion with the `<div data-role="collapsible">` itself. I'm trying to figure why it isn't working, as the content is loaded after the page is loaded.

Comment: try that. I added a class to the div and a jquery mobile function that should make each div an accordion item.